# How do I configure spice with KVM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, spice

I'm trying to install and configure [spice](http://spice-space.org/).

However, I cannot find a source on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Yes, I've done this with success in 12.04. What management tool are you using for running KVM? Virt-manager? plain Libvirt with `virsh`? a web based manager? or plain `qemu-kvm` command line, etc. And what guest OS are you running?

Comment: package easyspice seems to work on my 12.10 running in kvm.  Take a look at apt-cache pkgnames | grep spice   to see many more packages.

Comment: Hey I found this guide on the linux kvm site, not sure if you've seen it. How to install SPICE on KVM.
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE

Comment: I found the following resource useful:
https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to achive this using plain Libvirt with virsh.

First export the domain to XML:

```
virsh dumpxml <domain_name> > <domain_name>.xml
```

Then, edit the <domain_name>.xml file generated above and make sure the following is inside:

```
<devices>
...
<graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>                                                                                                                                                 
    <listen type='address'/>                                                                                                                                                             
    <image compression='off'/>                                                                                                                                                           
</graphics>
...
</devices>
```

Undefine the previous domain:

```
virsh undefine <domain_name>
```

Define the new domain using the XML edited:

```
virsh define <domain_name>.xml
```

After that you can connect to the SPICE on port 5900 using tools like virt-viewer, remote-viewer, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use 'aqemu', can be found in Ubuntu Repositories. It saves kvm configs to /home/${user}/.aqemu/